# Delphi, FireDAC, MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

```pascal
qClient.SQL.Clear;
qClient.SQL.Text := 'Select C.Lastname,C.Firstname,C.Clino,C.Address,' +
                    'C.City,C.State,C.Zip,C.Phone,C.HerCell,C.HisCell,' +
                    'C.Texting,C.Since,C.Selected,' +
                    'SUM( I.Charges - I.Discount ) as Revenue ' +
                    'from Client C join Invoice I ' +
                    'on I.Clino = C.Clino ' +
                    'where I.Date between :S and :E ' +
                    'and I.Inv = true ' +
                    'group by C.Clino ' +
                    'order by Revenue desc ';
qClient.ParamByName('S').AsDate := dStart;
qClient.ParamByName('E').AsDate := dEnd;
qClient.DetailFields := 'Clino';
qClient.Open();
```

How can I modify the above code so that the query includes only 'Revenue' values over a minimum (like maybe 1000)?  It currently includes all clients.

Thanks,
Spyke

Answer (score 1):

You need a `HAVING` clause:

```pascal
qClient.SQL.Text := 'Select C.Lastname,C.Firstname,C.Clino,C.Address,' +
                    'C.City,C.State,C.Zip,C.Phone,C.HerCell,C.HisCell,' +
                    'C.Texting,C.Since,C.Selected,' +
                    'SUM( I.Charges - I.Discount ) as Revenue ' +
                    'from Client C join Invoice I ' +
                    'on I.Clino = C.Clino ' +
                    'where I.Date between :S and :E ' +
                    'and I.Inv = true ' +
                    'group by C.Clino ' +
                    'having Revenue > 1000 ' +
                    'order by Revenue desc ';
```

The `HAVING` clause applies conditions and filters the results of the query after the aggregation.
In this case `Revenue` is an aggregated column and could not be used in a `WHERE` clause which also filters a query, because the conditions of the `WHERE` clause are applied before the aggregation.

Comment: The "having" clause solved my problem.  How do I acknowledge this?  This is my first time to use this forum.

Comment: @JimSawyer You can read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399